# CSS help me placing these divs please

Tags: html, css, css-float, divider

I have been having fun with CSS lately. Learning different things.

I'm trying to place three divs like this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/miN9G.png

What I get:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/eST25.png

(Need to post images as link. need more rep. I'll fix it when I get enough)

Should I add another div, set the class to example 'placeholder'
make the width to the same size as 'info'?

If you could make a small example I'll put that code into my code.

Comment: Where is your code? While you're at it, try creating a reduced test case (as a code snippet or on JSfiddle) to better explain the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this is what you want?

```css
.left {
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #111;
 margin: 2px;
}
.right {
 float: left;
 width: 200px;
 margin: 2px;
}
.right-1 {
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #111;
 margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.right-2 {
 float: left;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
  

<div class="left"> </div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="right-1"> </div>
  <div class="right-2"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh, I'll try that. I think that will work. Thanks. Need to tweak it though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have box 1,2 and 3. First you need to split box 1 from 2 and 3. Create two float divs, the problem you are having is probably because you are having it al on the same level. An example code as below

```
<div id="box1" style="float:left; width: 200px"></div>
<div style="float:left; width: 200px">
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="box3"></div>
</div>
```